# \newcommand and space between math formulas

Tags: spacing

If I define a new command like:

```
\newcommand{\expect}[2]{\mathbb{E}_{#2}\left[#1\right]}
```

which produces for

```
\expect{x}{y^2}
```

[image]

How can I get rid of the small space between the expectation and [].

Comment: Why there is `\left[...\right]` and not only `[...]`? This `\left/\right` pair creates an inner atom in math list and this gives the spacing.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that. I use it because sometimes some expressions within [] are so to large like $$\mathbb{E}[(X_0)^2]$$

Comment: In this case, I guess that also the `\scriptspace` is added. The [mleftright](https://ctan.org/pkg/mleftright?lang=en) package might be interesting for you.

Comment: With `\left[(X_0)^2\right]` the brackets are oversized and the result is much worse than `[(X_0)^2]`.

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look. 
@egreg what would be good solution to '\int_{[0,1]}|\mathbb{E}[x_{1}^{K_y} -x_1]- \mathbb{E}[x_2^{K_y}-x_2]|' ?

Comment: @cogitoergoboom Look at my answer

Comment: @cogitoergoboom I made a slight change: the possible subscript should be an optional argument, since you seem not to always want it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The excess space is due to two factors:

1. the main one is from `\left[`;
2. the other space comes from `\scriptspace` because of the subscript to `\mathbb{E}`.

Before analyzing a solution, please consider the output of

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\left[(\hat{X}_0)^2\right] \quad [(\hat{X}_0)^2]
\]
\end{document}
```

and judge for yourself whether you really want to apply `\left` and `\right` indiscriminately.

[image]

Now a possible solution with `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`. First we typeset the operator “E” with its subscript, then delegate the rest to `\expectvalue`.

Due to the possible absence of the subscript, I make the relevant argument optional.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\NewDocumentCommand{\expec}{sO{}mo}{%
  \operatorname{\mathbb{E}}%
  \IfValueT{#4}{_{#4}\kern-\scriptspace}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\expectvalue*{#3}}{\expectvalue[#2]{#3}}%
}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\expectvalue}{[}{]}

\begin{document}
\[
\expec{x}[y^2] \quad
\expec{(X_0)^2}[y^2] \quad
\expec[\big]{(X_0)^2}[y^2] \quad
\expec[\big]{(\hat{X}_0)^2}[y^2] \quad
\expec*{(\hat{X}_0)^2}[y^2] % wrong!
\]

\[
\int_{[0,1]}\bigl|\expec{x_{1}^{K_y} -x_1} - \expec{x_2^{K_y}-x_2}\bigr|
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Look in the manual of `mathtools` for the features of `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`.

Comment: @campa There is no space between a `\mathop` and a `\mathopen`.